# the use of would/will

Tags: grammar

Hello native speakers,

Could you please teach me how to use will/would correctly?

There were a few times I saw people use would+verb+if+present tense.

For example, '

> The premium would increase if a claim is made.

If this is correct, what is the difference between the sentence above and the following sentence?

> The premium would increase if a claim were made.

Comment: Technically, the two valid options would be "The premium would increase if a claim were made," and "The premium will increase if a claim is made."  However, in practice, people are often slightly sloppy and say, "The premium would increase if a claim is made."

Comment: *...if a claim **was** made* would work too; plain old preterite tense (in this case *was*) often replaces the old irrealis form (*were*) nowadays